# Agregar producto al carrito y verificar que exista en woocomerce desde javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

tengo un codigo creado en code snippet y quiero hacerle un llamado con un parametro para poder agregar un producto al carrito si el producto ya esta en el carrito no lo agrega.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'check_if_product_in_cart');
function check_if_product_in_cart() {
$product_id  = intval( $_POST['post_id'] );
$product_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product_id );
$in_cart = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $product_id );
if ( !$in_cart ) {
    WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
}
}
```

quiero llamarla desde un botón donde solo puedo utilizar javascript

```
function llamar(){
 var post_id =3917;//store product id in post id variable
var qty = 1;//store quantity in qty variable
jQuery.ajax({
    url : 'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', //ajax object of localization
    type : 'post', //post method to access data
    data : 
    {
        action : 'check_if_product_in_cart', //action on prefix_ajax_add_foobar function
        post_id : post_id
    },

    success : function(response){
            alert("Product Added successfully..");        
    }

});

return false;

}
```

quisiera saber si hay forma de llamar esta funcion desde javacript ya que actualmente no me esta funcionando

Answer (score 0):

Hay muchas formas de hacer esto, yo prefiero hacerlo de la forma correcta según WordPress, que suele ser la más segura.

Primero registramos un nuevo archivo de Javascript y le agregamos un par de variables, como la url del archivo admin-ajax.php, un nonce (Token de seguridad) y la acción que vamos a ejecutar.

```
function enqueue_add_to_cart_file(){

    // Agregar nuestro Archivo JS
    wp_enqueue_script( 'add-cart-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/add-to-cart.js', array(), '1.0', true );

    // Pasamos los argumentos
    wp_localize_script( 'add-cart-script', 'wc_cart_vars', array(
        'ajaxurl'   => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'nonce'     => wp_create_nonce( 'add-cart-script' ),
        'action'    => 'wpm4_add_cart'
    ) );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_add_to_cart_file' );
```

Una vez encolemos nuestro archivo y nuestras variables podemos proceder a crear nuestra función.

```
function wpm4_wc_add_product_to_cart() {

    // Estado de la respuesta
    $status = true;

    // ID del producto
    $product_id = absint( $_POST['product_id'] );

    // Obtenemos el token de seguridad
    $nonce = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['nonce'] );

    // Verificamos el token
    if ( wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'add-cart-script' ) ) :

        // Obtenemos el carrito actual
        $cart = WC()->cart;
        if ( $cart ) :

            // Obtenemos los items del carrito
            $items = $cart->cart_contents;
            if ( $items ) :

                // Recorremos todos los items
                foreach ( $items as $item ) {
                    
                    // Verificamos si el ID del producto ya existe en el carrito
                    if ( $item['product_id'] == $product_id ) {
                        $status = false;
                        break;
                    }

                }

            endif;
        endif;

        if ( $status ) :

            // Agregamos el producto al carrito
            // Podemos configurar mas parametros como la cantidad si se desea
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, 1 );

            $respond = array(
                'status'    => 'ok',
                'message'   => 'Producto agregado al carrito'
            );

        else :

            $respond = array(
                'status'    => 'error',
                'message'   => 'El producto ya existen en el carrito'
            );

        endif;

    else :

        $respond = array(
            'status'    => 'error',
            'message'   => 'Token de autorización inválido.'
        );

    endif;

    // Retornamos una respuesta en JSON
    echo json_encode( $respond );

}
```

Esta función recibe el ID del producto y un nonce el cual es un token de seguridad para verificar que la petición se haga desde nuestra web.

Luego usando `WC()->cart` obtenemos el carrito actual y recorremos los items para verificar si nuestro producto se encuentra entre ellos.

Ahora solo encolamos nuestra función Ajax

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_wpm4_add_cart', 'wpm4_wc_add_product_to_cart' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wpm4_add_cart', 'wpm4_wc_add_product_to_cart' );
```

Ahora en nuestro Archivo add-to-cart.js solo creamos nuestra función JavaScript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    function add_to_cart( product_id ){

        // Enviamos nuestro ajax
        jQuery.ajax({
            url : wc_cart_vars.ajaxurl,
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                action : wc_cart_vars.action,
                nonce : wc_cart_vars.nonce,
                product_id : product_id,
            },
            beforeSend: function(){
                // code...
            },
            success: function(result){

                // Obtenemos Respuesta
                let respond = JSON.parse(result.substring(0, result.length - 1));

                // Mostramos una respuesta
                if ( respond.status == 'ok' ) {

                    // Si el producto se agrego
                    // code ...

                    console.log( respond.message );

                } else {

                    // Si el producto no se agrego
                    // code ...

                    console.log( respond.message );

                }

            }
        });

    }

});
```

Esta función envía una petición ajax al archivo admin-ajax.php, dentro de sus parámetros envia nuestro Token de seguridad, el ID del producto y la función que debe ejecutar, luego nos devuelve una respuesta en formato JSON, esa respuesta la podemos usar para mostrarla en el fronted o para realizar cualquier tipo de acción según se necesite.

Por último debes de hacer que se active la función, solo llama la función y agregale el ID del producto, puedes activarla al momento de dar click en algun boton pasandole el botón el ID del producto y luego pasársela a la función.

```
add_to_cart( 15 );
```

Esto debería de funcionar de forma correcta, puedes agregar más parámetros según necesites.